# /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lGL

Tags: 18.04, compiling, gcc, qt

*This post has been translated from German. For the original, please see the revision history.*

---

I have written the following program in Qt Creator.

The error message refers to Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 on a device with Intel i5.

I've been researching for days and have not found a solution yet.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QPushButton>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QPushButton button("Hallo Welt und so weiter");

    button.move(250,300);
    button.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

---

```
:-1: Fehler: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

---

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/opt/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib -o HalloWelt main.o   -L/opt/Qt/5.11.1/gcc_64/lib -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 
/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lGL
Makefile:254: recipe for target 'HalloWelt' failed
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [HalloWelt] Error 1
16:12:14: Der Prozess "/usr/bin/make" wurde mit dem Rückgabewert 2 beendet.
Fehler beim Erstellen/Deployment des Projekts HalloWelt (Kit: Desktop Qt 5.11.1 GCC 64bit)
Bei der Ausführung von Schritt "Make"
16:12:14: Verstrichene Zeit: 00:00.
```

Answer (score 1):

At first it is very strange that you have Qt in `/opt`.

The correct way would be to install Qt 5.9.5 and other development packages from repository:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-default build-essential checkinstall \
libc6-dev libssl-dev libexpat1-dev libgl1-mesa-dev libqt4-dev \
libavcodec-dev libavutil-dev pkg-config
```

Then compile your program with

```
g++ HalloWelt.cpp $(pkg-config --cflags Qt5Widgets) $(pkg-config --libs Qt5Widgets) -fPIC -o HalloWelt
```

And run with

```
./HalloWelt
```

[image: HalloWelt]

If you want to fix only `-lGL` error you should install one package:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-dev
```

Comment: apt-get install build-essential checkinstall libc6-dev  libssl-dev  libexpat1-dev  libgl1-mesa-dev  libqt4-dev libavcodec-dev  libavutil-dev pkg-config

Comment: @FahadNaeem please remove your comment from here and ask new question.

Comment: I ended up having unmet dependencies when I installed these packages. This solution does not work.